# Как выключить фоновый scrolling при открытии модального окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как выключить фоновый `scrolling` при открытии модального окна на `css` или `js`?

Comment: Стиль `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Я добавляю к body свойство `max-height: 100vh` и `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте **css** код, что бы при открытом модальном окне отображалась(была доступна) только область внутри открытого элемента, а остальное было скрыто (недостунпно):

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Вот пример кода на [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVbXBR) (bootstrap + jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onscroll = function(){
  return false;
}
```

Comment: А если в модалке надо будет что-нибудь проскроллить?

Comment: У нас тут всё добровольно ) и пока что ваш ответ решает проблему не лучшим образом.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; выключает скролл
document.body.style.overflow = "";       включает скролл
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

```css
main {
  height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.popup:before {
  content: " ";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="popup">
    <p>غينيا واستمر العصبة ضرب قد. وباءت الأمريكي الأوربيين هو به،, هو العالم، الثقيلة بال. مع وايرلندا الأوروبيّون كان, قد بحق أسابيع العظمى واعتلاء.
    <p>غينيا واستمر العصبة ضرب قد. وباءت الأمريكي الأوربيين هو به،, هو العالم، الثقيلة بال. مع وايرلندا الأوروبيّون كان, قد بحق أسابيع العظمى واعتلاء.
    <p>غينيا واستمر العصبة ضرب قد. وباءت الأمريكي الأوربيين هو به،, هو العالم، الثقيلة بال. مع وايرلندا الأوروبيّون كان, قد بحق أسابيع العظمى واعتلاء.
    <p>غينيا واستمر العصبة ضرب قد. وباءت الأمريكي الأوربيين هو به،, هو العالم، الثقيلة بال. مع وايرلندا الأوروبيّون كان, قد بحق أسابيع العظمى واعتلاء.
  
  </div>
</main>
```